# meteor database insert in global collection

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

The code below should insert the selected item value in the Tasks collection, retain the info for later use, and a headerLabel should show the task selected. I am not able to get the headerLabel to show the task when the click .menuItem function runs. Thanks

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': function(event){
   Tasks.insert({menuItem: $(event.currentTarget).data('value')});
 }
});

Template.header.helpers({
 headerLabel: function( id ){
 return Tasks.findOne({_id: id}).menuItem;
 },
  tasks: function(){
  return Tasks.find();
 }
});

<template name="mainMenu">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <section class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="list-group">
      {{#each menuItems}}
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item menuItem" data-value={{menuItem}}>
          <img src="/abc.png">
          {{menuItem}} <span class="badge">&#x3e;</span>
        </a>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

```
<template name="header">
 <h1><button class="col-xs-2 mainMenu" type="button">&#9776;</button></h1>
 <h3>
   <label class="col-xs-8 text-center">
     {{#if headerLabel}} {{headerLabel}}  {{else}} Select an item {{/if}}
   </label>
</h3>
<h1><button class="col-xs-2" type="button">&#8942;</button></h1>
</template>
```

Comment: what do you mean? click event doesn't trigger or insert not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the click can happen multiple times, you'll need to pass an _id for the appropriate task into your helper:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': function(event){
   Tasks.insert({menuItem: $(event.currentTarget).data('value')});
 }
});

Template.header.helpers({
  headerLabel: function( id ){
    var task = Tasks.findOne({_id: id});
    if( task ) {
      return task.menuItem;
    }
  },
  tasks: function() {
    return Tasks.find();
  }
});
```

So what I'm doing there is saying find one task's menuItem that has the ID passed to the helper.  I also added a `tasks` helper to get all tasks.  So your template might look something like:

```
<template name="mainMenu">
    {{#each task in tasks}}
        <h4>{{headerLabel task._id}}</h4>
        <!-- Additional code here... -->
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

You'll obviously need to customize the HTML to your specific situation, but that should give you the gist.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I posted the templates, headerLabel is not showing the menuItem which is being clicked.

Comment: Did you fix the helpers like I suggested?

Comment: Yes, and posted the updated suggestion for confirmation.

Comment: So is the Task object getting inserted properly?  When you do `Tasks.find().fetch()` in the console do you get what you expect?

Comment: Yes. But initial page reload gives (Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'menuItem' of undefined
    at Object.Template.header.helpers.headerLabel )

Comment: Great. No console error. But the headerLabel is not changing to the menuItem being clicked. I posted the templates Would you please take a look. :) Thx

Comment: red line under "let" and my IDE says (not supported by current javaScript version.) hummmm

Comment: Sorry, that's ES6 syntax.  Updated answer.